# ASPX VB.Net OleDb Insert Parameter into Query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

This is my first time writing in VB.Net for aspx pages.

The problem I having is that the parameter is not going into the query at the line for `cmd.Parameters.Add`.

The error I am getting is

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

on the line

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader;
```

I have tried:

- Adding the `PARAMETERS` at the top of the query like I have shown;
- Removing and Adding `[]` around the parameter;
- Changing `OleDbType.Integer` to `OleDbType.SmallInt` or `OleDbType.BigInt`

I know the query works as I can place it into MS Access and will run once I add the parameter. But not when I run it in Visual Studio.

```
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim SQL As String = "PARAMETERS [@ID] Long; " &
                    "SELECT tblField.FieldName, " &
                           "tblField.FieldCaption, " &
                           "tblField.FieldMinCharNum, " &
                           "tblField.FieldMaxCharNum, " &
                           "tblField.FieldDefault, " &
                           "tblField.FieldSection, " &
                           "tblField.FirstQuestion, " &
                           "tblField.FieldDescription, " &
                           "tblField.FieldRegEx " &
                     "FROM tblField " &
                     "WHERE tblField.FieldID = [@ID];"

cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Connection.Connection)
cmd.Parameters.Add("[@ID]", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

I have a work around to make it work by just pre-inserting the parameter into the SQL string. But I want to make this work for other areas of the page that are yet to be written. Where user inputs are coming back into database so inputs are sanitised.

Comment: Get rid of the first line of the SQL code.  All you need is the `SELECT` statement. Also get rid of the brackets around the parameter. Brackets are used to force something to be interpreted as an identifier so you only put them around identifiers and, even then, they are only required if the text would not be interpreted as an identifier otherwise, i.e. it is a reserved word or contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the database?  That's what determines what data type you use for the parameter.  It's not arbitrary and there's no need to guess.  As the documentation states, `BigInt` is for 64-bit numbers, `Integer` is for 32-bit numbers and `SmallInt` is for 16-bit numbers.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The field is an Access AutoNumber so 32-bit which is why I tried Integer first but changed it just to make sure that I am not making a mistake.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The `[]` around the variables where originally not there and it made no difference. I added them to make sure. And the `PARAMETERS` was added after it failed the first time to see if that would fix it.

Comment: The code you posted is obviously wrong. Edit your question and post the code that you think it should be and we'll deal with that.

Comment: Also, recommend against using string concatenation like that to build SQL code.  It's not wrong but it's more likely to let you sneak an error in.  I'd suggest using an XML literal or in VB 2015 or later, a multiline `String` literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLEDB doesn't use @ to identify parameters. It uses ? and allocates parameters in the order they appear in the SQL amend your code to...

```
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT tblField.FieldName, " &
                           "tblField.FieldCaption, " &
                           "tblField.FieldMinCharNum, " &
                           "tblField.FieldMaxCharNum, " &
                           "tblField.FieldDefault, " &
                           "tblField.FieldSection, " &
                           "tblField.FirstQuestion, " &
                           "tblField.FieldDescription, " &
                           "tblField.FieldRegEx " &
                      "FROM tblField " &
                     "WHERE tblField.FieldID = ?"

cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Connection.Connection)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your mentioning SQL are you retrieving the data from SQL Query or are you going to insert data into the table.

your using `Dim cmd As OleDbCommand` means use to insert the input values into the database like see below sample code.

```
       query = "INSERT INTO ds.students (ID,NAME,PIC)" & _
       "VALUES (@ID,@NAME,@PIC);"
        Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", Convert.ToString(TextBox2.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PIC", arrImage)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
```

you can try this also

```
Using cn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(connectionString)

    cn.Open()

    Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

        Const sql As String = "Insert into test_table (val1, val2) values (:var1, :var2)"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("var1", TxtField1.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("var2", TxtField2.Text))
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using

End Using
```

if you want to insert the values into the database change your code according to given samples.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You'r first example won't work against Oracle as it uses colons to identify parameters. The @ is used by SQL/Server.